# remove last chars from NSString

Tags: objective-c, string, macos, core-foundation

I have a `NSString` and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to `remove spaces` and then take the `last 30 characters` of it.

Errors like:

`3/5/13 3:38:30 PM *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x160bf20'`

or

`3/5/13 3:30:51 PM *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x160bf20'`

I dont understand these errors.

Code:

```
NSString* m = (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(diskDesc, kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey);
[m stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]    
NSString *newString = [m substringToIndex:[m length]-30];
```

Another Update:

```
NSString * m = (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(diskDesc, kDADiskDescriptionDeviceModelKey);
NSString * v = (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(diskDesc, kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey);

if(m)
{
    m = [m stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
}

if(v)
{
    if([v length] > 30)
    {
        NSString *newString = [v substringToIndex:[v length]-30];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your errors indicate that you don't have a `CFStringRef` at all. You probably have some garbage object.

Comment: It might be useful to show some code of how you are removing spaces and then taking the last 30 characters of it...

Comment: instead of `if (m)` try `if ([m isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])`

Comment: Your problem is that you are casting to NSString something that is not an NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take note of the documentation in the DADisk.h header file, which specifies the type of result the dictionary will hold for a particular key:

```
extern const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey;      /* ( CFUUID       ) */

extern const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionDeviceModelKey;     /* ( CFString     ) */
```

All of the keys themselves are `NSString`/`CFString`s, but when you ask the dictionary for the value for that key, nothing says it has to be a string. The value in parenthesis to the right shows the type of value held for that key.

To get a string representation of the `CFUUID` that the `kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey` key holds, you can use CFUUIDCreateString():

```
CFUUIDRef UUID = (CFUUIDRef)[(NSDictionary *)diskDesc
               objectForKey:(id)kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey];

NSString *UUIDString = [(id)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, UUID) autorelease];
```

Also, the code for removing the extraneous spaces on `kDADiskDescriptionDeviceModelKey` should likely be the following:

```
NSString *deviceModel = [(NSDictionary *)diskDesc
              objectForKey:(id)kDADiskDescriptionDeviceModelKey];

NSLog(@"deviceModel == '%@'", deviceModel);

NSCharacterSet *whitespaceCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet
                                  whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];

deviceModel = [deviceModel stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespaceCharacterSet];

NSLog(@"deviceModel == '%@'", deviceModel);
```

That code logged the following for me:

```
diskArbitrationFinagler[] deviceModel == 'WDC WD6400AAKS-41H2B0                   '
diskArbitrationFinagler[] deviceModel == 'WDC WD6400AAKS-41H2B0'
```

Your `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` would incorrectly remove the space between `WDC` and `WD64....`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a great opportunity for error checking.  Like this:

```
NSString * m = (NSString*)CFDictionaryGetValue(diskDesc, kDADiskDescriptionDeviceModelKey);
if(m)
{
    m = [m stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]
    if([m length] > 30)
    {
        NSString *newString = [m substringToIndex:[m length]-30];
    } else {
        NSLog( @"m isn't even 30 characters");
    }
} else {
    NSLog( @"I didn't get anything useful from my call to CFDictionaryGetValue");
}
```

Comment: So I have what you are doing except the `NSMUtableString` from the original `NSString`. Why does yours work and mine crashes?

Comment: I've just done an update where I'm not using NSMutableString anymore.  "`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`" returns a new string, which you should be assigning to "`m`".

Comment: I updated my question with more code and it still does a crash like above

Comment: that's because "`kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey`" isn't necessary returning a string but is instead returning a "`CFUUID`" object. You need to figure out how to convert that into a string (CFStringRef or NSString).

Comment: but it is casted to an `(NSString)` and put in an `NSString` variable.  and according to `DADisk.h` `extern const CFStringRef kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey;      /* ( CFUUID       ) */`

Comment: I got it: `CFUUIDRef z = (CFUUIDRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(diskDesc, kDADiskDescriptionVolumeUUIDKey);
      CFStringRef j = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, z);
`